# $.get success function not getting executed

Tags: jquery

I am not sure if I am asking the right question in this forum but since this evening I am seeing some peculiar problems with my jQuery $.get function. Here is my code:

```
$.get(destinationURL, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $("#success").html("Mail sent successfully");
});
```

The problem is that success function is not getting executed even though I am getting the mail in my inbox. My console does not show any log (It should show "ok" as I have checked the URL separately and it is working perfectly. The problem is that this is such a small and simple piece of code that I cannot find any faults in this.

Can someone please help me with this problem???

Comment: My guess is `destinationURL` is a cross-origin url, or your server is throwing an error after the email function.

Comment: Does the server return anything ?

Comment: Look in the network tab in the browser's dev tools to see what response the request gives.

Comment: What type of control #success is?

Comment: This is what I get from the browser's log: XHR finished loading: "http://www.abc.comsndmail.php?email=xyz@gmail.com".

Comment: Check your server log to see if PHP is reporting an error.

Comment: No error reported. Everything normal in the error log. I will try to use $.ajax and see if the same happens.

Answer (score 0):

It might be calling error callback

```
    $.get(destinationURL ,function(data) {
                 console.log(data);
                 $("#success").html("Mail sent successfully");
            }).fail(function() { alert("error"); })
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It is indeed going in fail. But why? I am getting the email.

Comment: I believe you meant error instead of email, You getting error because your server is not returning success (200) in response

Comment: Sorry but I meant Email. I am receiving email on my mailbox and when I call the URL directly, I see a success. So what may be the reason for complete execution of the php script but returning error.

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi Sorry I did not read your question carefully. Make sure that you are setting correct response status(eg 200).